# What are () (parentheses) are for in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I searched in all the internet and didnt get a good answer on this thing.
What parentheses in python are stand for? its very wierd..
For example, if i do:

```
re.split(r'(/s*)', "ho from there")
```

its will give me a list of separate words with the spaces between that... how does its happening?

Comment: Parenthesis are used to [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) matching expressions.

Comment: Rather than 'search in all the internet', try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Or basic regex tutorials. Parentheses are an *extremely basic building block* when building regexes, no decent tutorial will leave those out. And the [`re.split()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) states: *If **capturing parentheses** are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.*.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to python, but in regex those denote a capture group.

Further information on how these are handled in re.split can be [seen here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)